# Change permissions of file uploaded by PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have created a small scale CMS for a website I am working on and have a form that uploads image files to be used on the website. It uploads the files successfully but the permissions it sets do not allow the file to be viewed in a browser.

Here is my current PHP code to upload the files

```
$typepath = $_POST['filetype'];

$target_path = "../../images/uploads/".$typepath."/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "<p>The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded</p>\n<p>To the directory:  <span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">".substr($target_path, 6)."</span></p>";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: Browser has nothing to do with file permissions. Can you please tell more real story, preferably with copy-pasted error messages? Thanks

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - yes it does. If the file doesn't have read permissions on the server, then the browser will get a `401 not authorised` error.

Comment: @Spudley it's 403. And it's still **server** issue, not browser one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

PHP Manaual `chmod` http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

```
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);
```

In context;

```
$typepath = $_POST['filetype'];

$target_path = "../../images/uploads/".$typepath."/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    chmod($target_path, 0755);
    echo "<p>The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded</p>\n<p>To the directory:  <span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">".substr($target_path, 6)."</span></p>";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: Be advised though: using chmod 755 means that the owner can read, write and execute. The group can now read and write. "Other" (anyone else) can read and write. Now, I assume that people won't be able to get into the directory, but if so, they could inject harmful stuff in your files. I'd always go for chmod 750 instead.

Comment: @Max Can you delete the files if you're using 644? Dont you need "execute" permission for that?

Comment: Will it set permissions for all users?