# PHP could not unlink recently uploaded file

Tags: php, unlink

PHP unlink throws "Permission denied" error when i try to unlink recently uploaded file.I can able to unlink older files.can someone help me?

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['researchfile']['tmp_name'], $path_of_file))
{
    if(file_exists($path_of_file) && is_file($path_of_file))    
        {
            unlink($path_of_file);  
        }
}
```

Comment: Was the file uploaded by php also? Part of the same script?

Comment: that means you need to change folder permission to 077 and files permission to 644

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4714841/4248328

Comment: Yes file uploaded and unlink are in same script

Comment: All permission are given. My problem is i couldn't unlink only recently uploaded file.

Comment: Can you share your code please.

Comment: It passed the file_exists and is_file conditions.

Comment: what is your platform? is it windows or linux? on windows you cannot remove opened file.

Comment: Windows.No files are opened. @Znik

Comment: @saron Have you ensured sufficient permissions are set ?

Comment: if uploader is the same process that deletor, then maybe system is unable to really close file on time, when you want delete it. ("thank you" Alive to Die, I won't make real answer because your minus.) . You can do some debug, before your move/unlink procedure insert some sleep, and check file is really not opened. Symptoms points, it is a chance file is still opened or semi closed. But you can do workaround. You can rename file adding suffix .todelete , and in next call try unlink all *.undelete files .